# Type Checking: typeof, GetType, or is?

Tags: c#, types, typeof, gettype

I've seen many people use the following code:

```
Type t = typeof(SomeType);
if (t == typeof(int))
    // Some code here
```

But I know you could also do this:

```
if (obj1.GetType() == typeof(int))
    // Some code here
```

Or this:

```
if (obj1 is int)
    // Some code here
```

Personally, I feel the last one is the cleanest, but is there something I'm missing? Which one is the best to use, or is it personal preference?

Comment: `as` isn't really type checking though...

Comment: `as` is certainly a form of type-checking, every bit as much as `is` is! It effectively uses `is` behind the scenes, and is used all over the place in MSDN in places where it improves code cleanliness versus `is`. Instead of checking for `is` first, a call to `as` establishes a typed variable that's ready for use: If it's null, respond appropriately; otherwise, proceed. Certainly something I've seen and used quite a bit.

Comment: There is significant performance difference in favor of `as`/`is` (covered in http://stackoverflow.com/a/27813381/477420) assuming its semantic works for your case.

Comment: @samusarin it doesn't "use" reflection. The `GetType` method you are linking to is in `System.Reflection.Assembly` -- a completely different method and irrelevant here.

Comment: I think what RCIC meant is that type check is usually followed by a cast and in such cases the type check (i.e. is) can be saved: var castedType = otherType as CastedType; if (castedType != null) { proceed with using object of type CastedType };

Answer (score 2250, accepted):

All are different.

- `typeof` takes a type name (which you specify at compile time).
- `GetType` gets the runtime type of an instance.
- `is` returns true if an instance is in the inheritance tree.

#### Example

```
class Animal { } 
class Dog : Animal { }

void PrintTypes(Animal a) { 
    Console.WriteLine(a.GetType() == typeof(Animal)); // false 
    Console.WriteLine(a is Animal);                   // true 
    Console.WriteLine(a.GetType() == typeof(Dog));    // true
    Console.WriteLine(a is Dog);                      // true 
}

Dog spot = new Dog(); 
PrintTypes(spot);
```

---

> What about `typeof(T)`? Is it also resolved at compile time?

Yes. T is always what the type of the expression is. Remember, a generic method is basically a whole bunch of methods with the appropriate type. Example:

```
string Foo<T>(T parameter) { return typeof(T).Name; }

Animal probably_a_dog = new Dog();
Dog    definitely_a_dog = new Dog();

Foo(probably_a_dog); // this calls Foo<Animal> and returns "Animal"
Foo<Animal>(probably_a_dog); // this is exactly the same as above
Foo<Dog>(probably_a_dog); // !!! This will not compile. The parameter expects a Dog, you cannot pass in an Animal.

Foo(definitely_a_dog); // this calls Foo<Dog> and returns "Dog"
Foo<Dog>(definitely_a_dog); // this is exactly the same as above.
Foo<Animal>(definitely_a_dog); // this calls Foo<Animal> and returns "Animal". 
Foo((Animal)definitely_a_dog); // this does the same as above, returns "Animal"
```

Comment: Ah, so if I have a Ford class that derives from Car and an instance of Ford, checking "is Car" on that instance will be true. Makes sense!

Comment: To clarify, I was aware of that, but I commented before you added a code sample. I wanted to try to add some plain English clarity to your already excellent answer.

Comment: @Shimmy if typeof is evaluated at compile time and GetType() is evaluated at runtime, then it makes sense that GetType() incurs a slight performance hit

Comment: what about new Dog().GetType() is Animal Or typeof(Dog) is Animal , it just gives a warning and not an error?

Comment: @PrerakK `new Dog().GetType() is Animal` returns false (and your other version as well) since `.GetType()` returns an object of type `Type`, and `Type` is not an `Animal`.

Comment: More generally, when you use `is`, if the result (either `true` or `false`) is known at compile-time, you get a compile-time warning. This means you should change your code! Example 1: `void M(Dog d) { var test = d is System.Exception; }` It can be seen at compile-time that a null reference or an instance of `Dog` can never be an instance of `System.Exception` because the involved types are `class` types and each `class` can have only one direct base class. Example 2: `void M(int i) { var test = i is IConvertible; }` It can be seen at compile-time that this is always true (`i` is never null).

Comment: I see your example working but seems to fail when the inheritance is Object to Int32... Parameter is Object, i´m asking parameter is Int32 = false, it should be true.

Comment: Hi @Yogurtu, `test(Object o) { return o is Int32; }` will return true for `test(10)`.

Comment: The topic of Reflections and these methods used is very useful and at the same time it is a bit complicated and needs more study and work in this field.

Comment: Good to know when using the anti-pattern factory design pattern.

Answer (score 251):

Use `typeof` when you want to get the type at *compilation time*.  Use `GetType` when you want to get the type at *execution time*.  There are rarely any cases to use `is` as it does a cast and, in most cases, you end up casting the variable anyway.

There is a fourth option that you haven't considered (especially if you are going to cast an object to the type you find as well); that is to use `as`.

```
Foo foo = obj as Foo;

if (foo != null)
    // your code here
```

This only uses **one** cast <s>whereas this approach:</s>

```
if (obj is Foo)
    Foo foo = (Foo)obj;
```

requires **two**.

**Update (Jan 2020):**

- [As of C# 7+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast), you can now cast inline, so the 'is' approach can now be done in one cast as well.

Example:

```cs
if(obj is Foo newLocalFoo)
{
    // For example, you can now reference 'newLocalFoo' in this local scope
    Console.WriteLine(newLocalFoo);
}
```

Comment: With the changes in .NET 4 does `is` still perform a cast?

Comment: Is this answer correct? Is it true that you really can pass an instance into typeof()? My experience has been No. But I guess it's generally true that checking an instance might have to happen at runtime, whereas checking a class should be doable at compile time.

Comment: @jon (4 yrs after your q.), no, you cannot pass an instance into `typeof()`, and this answer doesn't suggest you can. You pass in the type instead, i.e., `typeof(string)` works, `typeof("foo")` does not.

Comment: I don't believe `is` performs cast as such, rather special operation in IL.

Comment: We can now do `if (obj is Foo foo) { /* use foo here */ }`

Comment: "There are rarely any cases to use is as it does a cast and, in most cases, you end up casting the variable anyway." - There is actually a very valid use case of "is". See JoelC's answer. You can use is to typecheck and cast inline. It's very neat. Of course this is only available in C#7 and above I believe.

Answer (score 106):

**1.**

```
Type t = typeof(obj1);
if (t == typeof(int))
```

This is illegal, because `typeof` only works on types, not on variables. I assume obj1 is a variable. So, in this way `typeof` is static, and does its work at compile time instead of runtime.

**2.**

```
if (obj1.GetType() == typeof(int))
```

This is `true` if `obj1` is exactly of type `int`. If `obj1` derives from `int`, the if condition will be `false`.

**3.**

```
if (obj1 is int)
```

This is `true` if `obj1` is an `int`, or if it derives from a class called `int`, or if it implements an interface called `int`.

Comment: Thinking about 1, you're right. And yet, I've seen it in several code samples here. It should be Type t = obj1.GetType();

Comment: Yep, I think so. "typeof(obj1)" doesn't compile when I try it.

Comment: It's impossible to derive from System.Int32 or any other value type in C#

Comment: can you tell what would be typeof(typeof(system.int32))

Comment: @Sana, why don't you try it :) I would imagine though you get back an instance of  System.Type that represents the type System.Type! Documentation for typeof is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/typeof

Answer (score 63):

```
Type t = typeof(obj1);
if (t == typeof(int))
    // Some code here
```

This is an error.  The typeof operator in C# can only take type names, not objects.

```
if (obj1.GetType() == typeof(int))
    // Some code here
```

This will work, but maybe not as you would expect.  For value types, as you've shown here, it's acceptable, but for reference types, it would only return true if the type was the *exact same* type, not something else in the inheritance hierarchy.  For instance:

```
class Animal{}
class Dog : Animal{}

static void Foo(){
    object o = new Dog();

    if(o.GetType() == typeof(Animal))
        Console.WriteLine("o is an animal");
    Console.WriteLine("o is something else");
}
```

This would print `"o is something else"`, because the type of `o` is `Dog`, not `Animal`.  You can make this work, however, if you use the `IsAssignableFrom` method of the `Type` class.

```
if(typeof(Animal).IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType())) // note use of tested type
    Console.WriteLine("o is an animal");
```

This technique still leaves a major problem, though.  If your variable is null, the call to `GetType()` will throw a NullReferenceException.  So to make it work correctly, you'd do:

```
if(o != null && typeof(Animal).IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType()))
    Console.WriteLine("o is an animal");
```

With this, you have equivalent behavior of the `is` keyword.  Hence, if this is the behavior you want, you should use the `is` keyword, which is more readable and more efficient.

```
if(o is Animal)
    Console.WriteLine("o is an animal");
```

In most cases, though, the `is` keyword still isn't what you really want, because it's usually not enough just to know that an object is of a certain type.  Usually, you want to actually *use* that object as an instance of that type, which requires casting it too.  And so you may find yourself writing code like this:

```
if(o is Animal)
    ((Animal)o).Speak();
```

But that makes the CLR check the object's type up to two times.  It will check it once to satisfy the `is` operator, and if `o` is indeed an `Animal`, we make it check again to validate the cast.

It's more efficient to do this instead:

```
Animal a = o as Animal;
if(a != null)
    a.Speak();
```

The `as` operator is a cast that won't throw an exception if it fails, instead returning `null`.  This way, the CLR checks the object's type just once, and after that, we just need to do a null check, which is more efficient.

But beware: many people fall into a trap with `as`.  Because it doesn't throw exceptions, some people think of it as a "safe" cast, and they use it exclusively, shunning regular casts.  This leads to errors like this:

```
(o as Animal).Speak();
```

In this case, the developer is clearly assuming that `o` will *always* be an `Animal`, and as long as their assumption is correct, everything works fine.  But if they're wrong, then what they end up with here is a `NullReferenceException`.  With a regular cast, they would have gotten an `InvalidCastException` instead, which would have more correctly identified the problem.

Sometimes, this bug can be hard to find:

```
class Foo{
    readonly Animal animal;

    public Foo(object o){
        animal = o as Animal;
    }

    public void Interact(){
        animal.Speak();
    }
}
```

This is another case where the developer is clearly expecting `o` to be an `Animal` every time, but this isn't obvious in the constructor, where the `as` cast is used.  It's not obvious until you get to the `Interact` method, where the `animal` field is expected to be positively assigned.  In this case, not only do you end up with a misleading exception, but it isn't thrown until potentially much later than when the actual error occurred.

In summary:

- If you only need to know whether or not an object is of some type, use `is`.
- If you need to treat an object as an instance of a certain type, but you don't know for sure that the object will be of that type, use `as` and check for `null`.
- If you need to treat an object as an instance of a certain type, and the object is supposed to be of that type, use a regular cast.

Comment: what is wrong with this if(o is Animal)
    ((Animal)o).Speak(); ?  can you please give more details?

Comment: @batmaci: it's in the answer -- it causes two type checks. The first time is `o is Animal`, which requires the CLR to check if the type of the variable `o` is an `Animal`. The second time it checks is when it casts in the statement `((Animal)o).Speak()`. Rather than check twice, check once using `as`.

Comment: I found this an absolutely great explanation, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 23):

If you're using C# 7, then it is time for an update to Andrew Hare's great answer. [Pattern matching](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/02/01/pattern-matching.aspx) has introduced a nice shortcut that gives us a typed variable within the context of the if statement, without requiring a separate declaration/cast and check:

```
if (obj1 is int integerValue)
{
    integerValue++;
}
```

This looks pretty underwhelming for a single cast like this, but really shines when you have many possible types coming into your routine. The below is the old way to avoid casting twice:

```
Button button = obj1 as Button;
if (button != null)
{
    // do stuff...
    return;
}
TextBox text = obj1 as TextBox;
if (text != null)
{
    // do stuff...
    return;
}
Label label = obj1 as Label;
if (label != null)
{
    // do stuff...
    return;
}
// ... and so on
```

Working around shrinking this code as much as possible, as well as avoiding duplicate casts of the same object has always bothered me. The above is nicely compressed with pattern matching to the following:

```
switch (obj1)
{
    case Button button:
        // do stuff...
        break;
    case TextBox text:
        // do stuff...
        break;
    case Label label:
        // do stuff...
        break;
    // and so on...
}
```

EDIT: Updated the longer new method to use a switch as per Palec's comment.

Comment: Using [`switch` statement with pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#type-pattern) is advisable in this case.

Comment: How would you cope with a is not ? In this particular code block?
`if (obj1 is int integerValue)
{
    integerValue++;
}`

Comment: Ben, if I understand your question, I would just have an else statement to handle other cases since you can't put a not integer into an integer variable. :)

Comment: I needed to set an enum based on a type, but not use the actual variable. So, I just used the switch/case pattern matching with discards (`_`). e.g. `case Button _:`. Works great, much less noise than a big if statement.

Answer (score 16):

I had a `Type`-property to compare to and could not use `is` (like `my_type is _BaseTypetoLookFor`), but I could use these:

```
base_type.IsInstanceOfType(derived_object);
base_type.IsAssignableFrom(derived_type);
derived_type.IsSubClassOf(base_type);
```

Notice that `IsInstanceOfType` and `IsAssignableFrom` return `true` when comparing the same types, where IsSubClassOf will return `false`.  And `IsSubclassOf` does not work on interfaces, where the other two do.  (See also [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129277/how-do-you-determine-whether-or-not-a-give-type-system-type-inherits-from-a-sp/).)

```
public class Animal {}
public interface ITrainable {}
public class Dog : Animal, ITrainable{}

Animal dog = new Dog();

typeof(Animal).IsInstanceOfType(dog);     // true
typeof(Dog).IsInstanceOfType(dog);        // true
typeof(ITrainable).IsInstanceOfType(dog); // true

typeof(Animal).IsAssignableFrom(dog.GetType());      // true
typeof(Dog).IsAssignableFrom(dog.GetType());         // true
typeof(ITrainable).IsAssignableFrom(dog.GetType()); // true

dog.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Animal));            // true
dog.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Dog));               // false
dog.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(ITrainable)); // false
```

Answer (score 11):

I prefer **is**

That said, if you're using **is**, you're likely *not* using inheritance properly.

Assume that Person : Entity, and that Animal : Entity.  Feed is a virtual method in Entity (to make Neil happy)

```cs
class Person
{
  // A Person should be able to Feed
  // another Entity, but they way he feeds
  // each is different
  public override void Feed( Entity e )
  {
    if( e is Person )
    {
      // feed me
    }
    else if( e is Animal )
    {
      // ruff
    }
  }
}
```

Rather

```cs
class Person
{
  public override void Feed( Person p )
  {
    // feed the person
  }
  public override void Feed( Animal a )
  {
    // feed the animal
  }
}
```

Comment: True, I would never do the former, knowing that Person derives from Animal.

Comment: The latter isn't really using inheritance, either.  Foo should be a virtual method of Entity that is overridden in Person and Animal.

Comment: @bobobobo I think you mean "overloading", not "inheritance".

Comment: @lc:  No, I mean inheritance.

The first example is a kind of incorrect way (using _is_) to get different behavior.  The second example uses overloading yes, but avoids use of _is_.

Comment: Good point that using the 'is' keyword is generally poor design choice. However the solution provided doesn't fix the design it just changes how it is implemented.

Comment: The problem with the example is that it wouldn't scale. If you added  new entities that needed to eat (for example an Insect or a Monster) you would need to add a new method in the Entity class and then override it in subclasses that would feed it. This isn't any more preferable than a list if (entity is X) else if (entity is Y)...
This violates the LSP and OCP, inheritance probably isn't the best solution to the problem. Some form of delegation would probably be preferred.

Comment: It's a good idea to use a switch instead of a bunch of if statements, with this kind of type checking. The reason is Visual Studio has analyzers which will warn you if you are doing the checks in an order that would catch a less-derived type check before it gets a chance to be matched by a more-derived one. It doesn't appear to do that, when doing it in if-else constructs, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the last one also looks at inheritance (e.g. `Dog is Animal == true`), which is better in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what I'm doing. If I need a `bool` value (say, to determine if I'll cast to an `int`), I'll use `is`.  If I actually need the type for some reason (say, to pass to some other method) I'll use `GetType()`.

Comment: Good point. I forgot to mention that I got to this question after looking at several answers that used an if statement to check a type.

Answer (score 1):

I found checking if the type of something is equal to something is done by the following:

`variableName.GetType() == typeof(int)`

Answer (score 0):

The last one is cleaner, more obvious, and also checks for subtypes. The others do not check for polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

### Used to obtain the System.Type object for a type. A typeof expression takes the following form:

```
System.Type type = typeof(int);

Example:

    public class ExampleClass
    {
       public int sampleMember;
       public void SampleMethod() {}

       static void Main()
       {
          Type t = typeof(ExampleClass);
          // Alternatively, you could use
          // ExampleClass obj = new ExampleClass();
          // Type t = obj.GetType();

          Console.WriteLine("Methods:");
          System.Reflection.MethodInfo[] methodInfo = t.GetMethods();

          foreach (System.Reflection.MethodInfo mInfo in methodInfo)
             Console.WriteLine(mInfo.ToString());

          Console.WriteLine("Members:");
          System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] memberInfo = t.GetMembers();

          foreach (System.Reflection.MemberInfo mInfo in memberInfo)
             Console.WriteLine(mInfo.ToString());
       }
    }
    /*
     Output:
        Methods:
        Void SampleMethod()
        System.String ToString()
        Boolean Equals(System.Object)
        Int32 GetHashCode()
        System.Type GetType()
        Members:
        Void SampleMethod()
        System.String ToString()
        Boolean Equals(System.Object)
        Int32 GetHashCode()
        System.Type GetType()
        Void .ctor()
        Int32 sampleMember
    */
```

### This sample uses the GetType method to determine the type that is used to contain the result of a numeric calculation. This depends on the storage requirements of the resulting number.

```
    class GetTypeTest
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int radius = 3;
            Console.WriteLine("Area = {0}", radius * radius * Math.PI);
            Console.WriteLine("The type is {0}",
                              (radius * radius * Math.PI).GetType()
            );
        }
    }
    /*
    Output:
    Area = 28.2743338823081
    The type is System.Double
    */
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are only interested in the base types in an object and you need to handle it differently based on its type then you could do the following.

```
TypeCode typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(value.GetType());

switch (typeCode)
{
    case TypeCode.Empty:
    case TypeCode.DBNull:
        return "";

    case TypeCode.Boolean:
    case TypeCode.Object:
    case TypeCode.DateTime:
    case TypeCode.SByte:
    case TypeCode.Byte:
    case TypeCode.Int16:
    case TypeCode.UInt16:
    case TypeCode.Int32:
    case TypeCode.UInt32:
    case TypeCode.Int64:
    case TypeCode.UInt64:
    case TypeCode.Single:
    case TypeCode.Double:
    case TypeCode.Decimal:
        return "do something";
        
    case TypeCode.Char:
    case TypeCode.String:
    default:
        return value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
if (c is UserControl) c.Enabled = enable;
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Your answer is unrelated to the question.

Answer (score -5):

You can use "typeof()" operator in C# but you need to call the namespace using System.IO; You must use "is" keyword if you wish to check for a type.

Comment: `typeof` is not defined in a namespace, it is a keyword. `System.IO` has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score -5):

Performance test typeof() vs GetType():

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
    class Program
    {
        enum TestEnum { E1, E2, E3 }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {
                var start = DateTime.UtcNow;
                for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
                    Test1(TestEnum.E2);
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow - start);
            }
            {
                var start = DateTime.UtcNow;
                for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
                    Test2(TestEnum.E2);
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow - start);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static Type Test1<T>(T value) => typeof(T);
        static Type Test2(object value) => value.GetType();
    }
}
```

Results in debug mode:

```
00:00:08.4096636
00:00:10.8570657
```

Results in release mode:

```
00:00:02.3799048
00:00:07.1797128
```

Comment: One should not use DateTime.UtcNow for performance measures. With your code but with Stopwatch class I got persistently opposite results for Debug mode.

UseTypeOf:   00:00:14.5074469
UseGetType: 00:00:10.5799534

. Release mode is the same, as expected

Comment: @AlexeyShcherbak The difference between Stopwatch and DateTime.Now cannot be more than 10-20 ms, check your code again. And I don't care about milliseconds in my test. Also my code will be several lines of code longer with Stopwatch.

Comment: it's bad practice in general, not in your particular case.

Comment: @AlexanderVasilyev Amount of lines of code should never be used as an argument to do something _documentedly_ misleading.
As seen in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx, `DateTime` should not be used if you're concerned about times below *100ms*, since it uses the OS's timeframe. Comparatively with `Stopwatch`, which uses the processors' `Tick`, the resolution used by a `DateTime` in Win7 is a whooping 15ms.