# How to check if an object its *exactly* a class, not a derived one?

Tags: c#, inheritance

There is any way to determine if an object is *exactly* a class and not a derived one of that?

For instance:

```
class A : X { }

class B : A { }
```

I can do something like this:

```
bool isExactlyA(X obj)
{
   return (obj is A) && !(obj is B);
}
```

Of course if there are more derived classes of `A` I'd have to add *and* conditions.

Answer (score 11):

Generalizing snicker's answer:

```
public static bool IsExactly<T>(this object obj) where T : class
{
  return obj != null && obj.GetType() == typeof(T);
}
```

and now you can say

```
if (foo.IsExactly<Frob>()) ...
```

Caveat: use extension methods on object judiciously. Depending on how widely you use this technique, this might not be justified.

Comment: @eric: just use some padding space within the message bounds to overcome the minimum length limit :)

Comment: Really nice touch to implement as an extension

Answer (score 5):

in your specific instance:

```
bool isExactlyA(X obj)
{
   return obj.GetType() == typeof(A);
}
```

Comment: typeof requires a type not a class

Answer (score 2):

I see...

```
control.GetType() ==  typeof(Label)
```

Comment: That's correct.  IF you do typeof(control), you always get Control.

Answer (score 0):

[More information about the `typeof` and `is` operators, as well as the GetType method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is)