# How to check if a class inherits another class without instantiating it?

Tags: c#, inheritance, types

Suppose I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Derived : // some inheritance stuff here
{
}
```

I want to check something like this in my code:

```
Derived is SomeType;
```

But looks like `is` operator need Derived to be variable of type Dervied, not Derived itself.
I don't want to create an object of type Derived.
How can I make sure Derived inherits `SomeType` without instantiating it?

**P.S.** If it helps, I want something like what `where` keyword does with generics.
**EDIT:**
Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1528695/279982) answer, but it's checking an object. I want to check the class itself.

Answer (score 377, accepted):

To check for  assignability, you can use the [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) method:

```
typeof(SomeType).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Derived))
```

This will work as you expect for type-equality, inheritance-relationships and interface-implementations but *not* when you are looking for 'assignability' across explicit / implicit conversion operators.

To check for strict inheritance, you can use [`Type.IsSubclassOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx):

```
typeof(Derived).IsSubclassOf(typeof(SomeType))
```

Comment: Just as a note to anyone else wondering, this won't return true when checking against generic type/interface definitions, as far as I can tell you need to search the inheritance chain and check for generic type definitions yourself.

Comment: Alex, how would you go about searching the inheritance chain of a generic type to accomplish this?

Comment: @AlexHopeO'Connor's note is important and I think solution is there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457676/check-if-a-class-is-derived-from-a-generic-class

Comment: For PCL `typeof(SomeType).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Derived).GetTypeInfo())`

Comment: For those a little confused about the order, such as myself: 
`typeof(InvalidOperationException).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Exception)) = false`
`typeof(Exception).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(InvalidOperationException)) = true`

Answer (score 25):

Try this

```
typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(BarClass));
```

This will tell you whether `BarClass(Derived)` implements `IFoo(SomeType)` or not