# GetType, typeof and is, to handle null and conversion

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Type Checking: typeof, GetType, or is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is)

What is the difference between the following:

```
bool isLong (object a){
    return (a.GetType()==typeof(INT64));
}

bool isLong (object a){
    return (typeof(a)==typeof(INT64));
}

bool isLong (object a){
    return (a is INT64);
}
```

In addition. there is an option that a will be null. Does those functions can handle such case?

(
I need to convert "value" to long? for example:
c.CustomerId = (long?)value;
)

can I use:
long? id=(a as long?)

Comment: Did you search before posting this?

Comment: @thecoop: I added a question about null. Please see the question.

Comment: Well, have you tried it in a test project to see what the behaviour is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first uses the instance `a` and will throw an exception if `a` is `null`. It compares the type using the `Type` class.

The second way won't work because `typeof` only works with type names, not instances.

In the last way, you are saying `a` is of type `INT64`. It not throw an exception if `a` is `null`. This is the preferred method.

However in your case, the conversion you could do

```
c.CustomerId = value as long?;
```

Comment: can I use: long? id=(a as long?)?

Comment: `is` always return `false` for `null`.

Comment: Absolutely - it will stick `null` into `id` if it can't do the conversion.