# The "is" keyword and the override of Equals method

Tags: c#, .net

The [documentation for the keyword "is"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) states that:

> The is operator only considers reference conversions, boxing
>   conversions, and unboxing conversions. Other conversions, such as
>   user-defined conversions, are not considered.

What does it mean in practice?
Is it wrong to use it to check if a struct is a certain type?
For example,

```
public struct Point2D
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    ...

    public override bool Equals(Object value)
    {
        if (value != null && value is Point2D)   // or if (value != null && GetType() == value.GetType())
        {
            Point2D right = (Point2D)value;
            return (X == right.X && Y == right.Y);
        }
        else return false;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: It is wrongish,  value.GetType() == typeof(Point2D) protects you against refactoring accidents.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is) the reason?

Comment: @enzom83 That is correct. `is` could be appropriate for this case, if you care about inheriting from Point2D, and want children to also have this same logic (by default)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking whether a struct is a certain type is fine.  The documentation means that user-defined [explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx) and [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) conversion operators are not evaluated when considering whether the given object is of the specified type, even if there is a user-defined operator that can convert it to said type.