# When and where to use GetType() or typeof()?

Tags: c#, .net, types, typeof, gettype

Why this works

```
if (mycontrol.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
{}
```

and this do not?

```
Type tp = typeof(mycontrol);
```

But this works

```
Type tp = mycontrol.GetType();
```

I myself use `is` operator for checking type but my understanding fails when I use `typeof()` and `GetType()`

Where and when to use `GetType()` or `typeof()`?

Comment: what do you mean by this works... and this not...?

Comment: @anouar204: Try them in your IDE.

Comment: Does not `compile` would be more appropriate than does not `work`

Comment: This seems to be the original version of this question, rather than the one listed as a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is

Answer (score 146, accepted):

[`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) is an operator to obtain a type known at *compile-time* (or at least a generic type parameter). The operand of `typeof` is always the name of a type or type parameter - *never* an expression with a value (e.g. a variable). See the [C# language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) for more details.

[`GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) is a method you call on individual objects, to get the *execution-time* type of the object.

Note that unless you *only* want exactly instances of `TextBox` (rather than instances of subclasses) you'd usually use:

```
if (myControl is TextBox)
{
    // Whatever
}
```

Or

```
TextBox tb = myControl as TextBox;
if (tb != null)
{
    // Use tb
}
```

Comment: Your Line `'The operand of typeof is always the name of a type or type parameter - never an expression with a value (e.g. a variable)'` is the perfect answer to my question. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 72):

`typeof` is applied to a name of a type or generic type parameter known at compile time (given as identifier, not as string). `GetType` is called on an object at runtime. In both cases the result is an object of the type `System.Type` containing meta-information on a type.

Example where compile-time and run-time types are **equal**:

```
string s = "hello";

Type t1 = typeof(string);
Type t2 = s.GetType();
```

> `t1 == t2                    ==> true`

Example where compile-time and run-time types are **different**:

```
object obj = "hello";

Type t1 = typeof(object); // ==> object
Type t2 = obj.GetType();  // ==> string!
```

> `t1 == t2                    ==> false`

i.e., the compile time type (static type) of the variable `obj` is not the same as the runtime type of the object referenced by `obj`.

---

**Testing types**

If, however, you only want to know whether `mycontrol` is a `TextBox` then you can simply test

```
if (mycontrol is TextBox)
```

Note that this is not completely equivalent to

```
if (mycontrol.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
```

because `mycontrol` could have a type that is derived from `TextBox`. In that case the first comparison yields `true` and the second `false`! The first and easier variant is OK in most cases, since a control derived from `TextBox` inherits everything that `TextBox` has, probably adds more to it and is therefore assignment compatible to `TextBox`.

```
public class MySpecializedTextBox : TextBox
{
}

MySpecializedTextBox specialized = new MySpecializedTextBox();
if (specialized is TextBox)       ==> true

if (specialized.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))        ==> false
```

---

**Casting**

If you have the following test followed by a cast and T is nullable ...

```
if (obj is T) {
    T x = (T)obj; // The casting tests, whether obj is T again!
    ...
}
```

... you can change it to ...

```
T x = obj as T;
if (x != null) {
    ...
}
```

Testing whether a value is of a given type and casting (which involves this same test again) can both be time consuming for long inheritance chains. Using the `as` operator followed by a test for `null` is more performing.

Starting with C# 7.0 you can simplify the code by using pattern matching:

```
if (obj is T t) {
    // t is a variable of type T having a non-null value.
    ...
}
```

Btw.: this works for value types as well. Very handy for testing and unboxing. Note that you cannot test for nullable value types:

```
if (o is int? ni) ===> does NOT compile!
```

This is because either the value is `null` or it is an `int`. The following code works for `int? o` as well as for `object o = new Nullable<int>(x);`:

```
if (o is int i) ===> OK!
```

I like it, because it eliminates the need to access the `Nullable<T>.Value` property.

Comment: The static type of `o` can be either `int?` or `object`. If e.g., `42` was assigned to `o`, then `o is int i` returns `true` and `i` is `42`. If `null` was assigned to `o` it returns `false` and `i` undefined.

Comment: Oh, because this tests the value, not the type as being declared. If an `int?` is assigned an integer, then the value is an `int`. If it is assigned `null` then the type is undefined. `null` does not have a type. But you can test `o.GetType() == typeof(int?)` to test for `int?`. Note that `Nullable<T>` has special compiler support as mentioned in the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs): *"[..] we have special type system support that says a boxed Nullable<T> can be used where a boxed<T> is used [..]"*

Answer (score 9):

[typeOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) is a C# keyword that is used when you have the name of the class. It is calculated at compile time and thus cannot be used on an instance, which is created at runtime. [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) is a method of the object class that can be used on an instance.

Answer (score 5):

You may find it easier to use the [`is` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx):

```
if (mycontrol is TextBox)
```

Comment: This answer i am finding all over SO and i know this.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: If you already know something which is an obvious answer to your question, you should say so in the question in order to avoid wasting people's time. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet: I use is keyword but was puzzled in typeof() and GetType()