# Getting properties of IEnumerable<T> (where T is object)

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, system.reflection

I have the following function:

```
public IEnumerable<string> PropertiesFromType<T>(IEnumerable<T> input)
```

From the type (`T`), I would like to get the names of the properties.

I have tried the following:

```
var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
//var properties = input.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperties(); // Doesn't work either
foreach (var item in properties)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}

// By input it does work
var inputProperties = input.First().GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var item in inputProperties)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

When sending an anonymous `IEnumerable<object>` into the function, it has no properties when retrieving the `Type` from `T`.

However, when using the `Type` of an item in the `IEnumerable`, it does have properties.

As suggested by: [How to get the type of T from a member of a generic class or method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/how-to-get-the-type-of-t-from-a-member-of-a-generic-class-or-method/557349#557349) using the GetGenericArguments function neither returns properties.

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/uKzO6H

Edit:
I guess what I was trying to say: Is it possible to get the `Type` of anonymous objects in an `IEnumerable` without having an instance of, by using the `T`.

I now realize that is impossible, as `T` will always be `object` for anonymous objects.

Comment: `foreach (string value in Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When and where to use GetType() or typeof()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312111/when-and-where-to-use-gettype-or-typeof)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Unfortunately not

Comment: @VDWWD See Pavel Anikhouski answer as to why that won't work

Comment: If you actually mean *anonymous types*, then no, they have proper properties as regular types does. In other words, if you feed it a collection of objects you constructed as `new { A = 42, B = "Meaning of life" }`, then you would find properties A and B on T. If you mean *dynamic* or just *`object`*, then you're right, you can't infer properties of each object from looking at the type of the collection, you need to query the type of each object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you want, but the method below takes the first element of the list and returns it's properties.

```
public IEnumerable<string> PropertiesFromType<T>(IEnumerable<T> input)
{
    var item = input.First();
    var properties = new List<string>();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in item.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        properties.Add(property.Name);
    }

    return properties;
}
```

Usage example

```
public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
}

var PropertyList = PropertiesFromType<Book>(MyListOfBooks);
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, it is close to what I was trying to achieve, however that appears to be impossible (properties of anonymous objects, as they can be different with each element in an IEnumerable)