# Overriding Equals: typeof returns the static type

Tags: c#, .net, msdn

In Microsoft's MSDN Library article on **Object.Equals Method (Object)**, (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) an example is presented to demonstrate how to override **Equals**. It looks like this:

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
    //Check for null and compare run-time types.
    if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType()) return false;
    // ...
}
```

In the ensuing documentation, my attention was drawn to the following statement.

*(Note that typeof is not used here because it returns the static type.)*

What does the above statement mean - in plain terms - and what is the caution here?

Comment: Oddly, they removed the exact sentence you quoted from .NET 4.5 document, which means you cannot find it in your link now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In their example, in the implementation of Point.Equals(), if typeof(Point) were used instead of GetType(), they wouldn't be able to leverage base.Equals() in the implementation of Point3D.Equals() because it would always return false.

By using GetType(), it ensures runtime evaluation of the types instead of hardcoding the type comparison to typeof(Point); it allows a subclass to lean on the base class for the type comparison while allowing the subclass to concentrate on the data it supplements the base class with.

Answer (score 2):

- typeof takes a type name (which you specify at compile time).
- GetType gets the runtime type of an instance.

  [Check here For Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is)