# Check Control is LinkButton?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How to check if this control is linkButton?

CType(e.Row.Cells(0).Controls(0), LinkButton)

This is inside grid view row data bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `TemplateFields` you should use `FindControl` to get the reference to your control:

```
LinkButton myLinkButton = (LinkButton) e.Row.FindControl("LinkButtonID");
```

To answer your question how to check the type:

[Type Checking: typeof, GetType, or is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is)

Another one is using `as` operator:

```
LinkButton myLinkButton = e.Row.Cells(0).Controls(0) as LinkButton;
if(myLinkButton != null); // successfull cast
```

**Edit** since `DataControlLinkButton` accessibility is [`Friend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08w05ey2(v=vs.90).aspx) you canot use it directly(apart from your own `GetType().ToString` approach). But because it inherits from `LinkButton` you can check that:

Via `Is`:

```
If TypeOf control Is LinkButton Then
    DirectCast(control, LinkButton).Visible = False
End If
```

Via `TryCast`(C# as operator):

```
Dim lbEdit = TryCast(e.Row.Cells(0).Controls(0), LinkButton)
If lbEdit IsNot Nothing Then
    lbEdit.Visible = False
End If
```

Via `GetType`:

```
If control.GetType() = GetType(LinkButton) Then
    DirectCast(control, LinkButton).Visible = False
End If
```

Comment: Its not TemplateFields  its the Edit Delete Buttons when we enable AutoGenerateDeleteButton & AutoGenerateEditButton.

Comment: @MohammadMMohammad:Why do you need it in `RowDataBound`?

Comment: My problem is when I'm exporting to excel I'm hiding these links but its catching error on this line since the first column in no longer a linkbutton. that is why I want to check if they are linkbuttons before assigning them orelse it will catch errors

Comment: @MohammadMMohammad: Why don't you hide the complete column(s)? `gridView1.Columns[0].Visible=false;`

Comment: This don't work with AutoGenerateDeleteButton & AutoGenerateEditButton as they are built it columns and not templateFields. When I did this it hide my first templateField I have in the grid...

Comment: For LinkButton myLinkButton = e.Row.Cells(0).Controls(0) as LinkButton; If the first column is not LinkButton in case I hide them its catching error that is why I want to check their type to check if they are LinkButton to proceed. was I clear for you with my problem here?

Comment: I did the checking, check my solution

Comment: don't forget to vote me up if you like my solution it works for me.

Comment: @MohammadMMohammad: I've edited my answer also to show you how you can check the types without using it's string representation (upvoted your answer anyway).

Answer (score 1):

```
 If e.Row.Cells(0).Controls(0).GetType().ToString = "System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlLinkButton" Then
   Dim lbEdit As LinkButton = CType(e.Row.Cells(0).Controls(0), LinkButton)
   lbEdit.Visible = False
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if((e.Row.Cells(0).Controls(0)) is LinkButton)
{ 
   ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells(0).Controls(0)).visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim lnkbtn As LinkButton = CType(e.Row.Findcontrol("lnkbuttonname"), LinkButton)

Protected Sub dgrd_WWWH_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles dgrd_WWWH.RowCommand

Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.CommandSource, LinkButton).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
Dim txtwwwhid = CType(row.FindControl("txtwwwhid"), Label)
Dim txtwho = CType(row.FindControl("txtWho"), LinkButton)
Dim txtwho1 = CType(row.FindControl("txtWho1"), LinkButton)

End Sub
```

Comment: Please expand this answer a bit with for example what would be expected if it isn't a `LinkButton`.