# Reflection in C# Superclass and Subclass

Tags: c#, object, inheritance, reflection, system.reflection

Friends,

Given these three classes:

```
public class MyBaseClass {
}

public class MyDerivedClass1: MyBaseClass {
}

public class MyDerivedClass2: MyBaseClass {
}
```

At runtime, I will have an object of type `MyBaseClass` (which will either be `MyDerivedClass2` or `MyDerivedClass1`). How can I determine, at runtime if `MyBaseClass` is `MyDerivedClass1`?

Comment: the last 4 words of your question is your answer

Comment: Haha @Sayse... I must admit that for some reason, that comment tickled me.

Answer (score 5):

Using the `is` operator.

> **is (C# Reference)** - Checks if an object is compatible with a given type. For example, the following code can determine if an object is an instance of the MyObject type, or a type that derives from MyObject:

**The [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) operator returns true if an instance is in the inheritance tree.**

```
if (myInstance is MyDerivedClass1) 
{
    // my instance is of type MyDerivedClass1
}
```

This will work with your sample code. **BUT** if you want to check if its exactly the same type you need to use `typeof()` and `GetType()`.

```
if (myInstance.GetType() == typeof (MyDerivedClass1))
{
    // my instance is of type MyDerivedClass1
}
```

#### More Information

- [Type Checking: typeof, GetType, or is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is)

Comment: Be aware of the order! `myInstance is MyBaseClass` will match `MyDerivedClass1` too!

Answer (score 1):

**1.** If you want to be sure whether the instance is **exactly** of the given type you should use [GetType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx) method and compare it with desired type:

```
bool IsExactlyOfMyDerivedClass2(object instance)
{
    if (instance == null)
        throw new ArgnumentNullException();

    return (instance.GetType() == typeof(MyDerivedClass2))
}
```

or generic version

```
bool IsExactlyOf<T>(object instance)
{
    if (instance == null)
        throw new ArgnumentNullException();

    return (object.GetType() == typeof(T))
}
```

**2.** If you does not care whether the instance is exactly of the given type (or the type is abstract class or interface) you, as it has been pointed by @dknaack use the [IS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) C# operator:

```
bool IsOfMyDerivedClass2_OrMoreDerived(object instance)
{
    if (instance == null)
        throw new ArgnumentNullException();

    return instance is MyDerivedClass;
}
```

**3.** Also, you can also use the [IsAssignable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx) method of [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
bool IsOfMyDerivedClass2_OrMoreDerived(object instance)
{
    if (instance == null)
        throw new ArgnumentNullException();

    return typeof(MyDerivedClass2).IsAssignableFrom(instance.GetType());
}
```

or generic version:

```
bool IsOf_OrMoreDerived<T>(object instance)
{
    if (instance == null)
        throw new ArgnumentNullException();

    return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(instance.GetType());
}
```

Comment: a couple things, `object.GetType()` should be `instance.GetType()` and then you can just return the result of your final if statement

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the types at compile time (ie you only have access to Type objects), you can use [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx) (or TypeInfo.IsAssignableFrom depending on which Platform you are).

```
var baseClassType = typeof(BaseClass);
var derivedClassType = typeof(DerivedClass);
var isBaseClass = baseClassType.IsAssignableFrom(derivedClassType);
```