# ("Child Class" is "Parent class")

Tags: c#

I am having a HotDog class as a child of Food class.

```
public class HotDog : Food
{
    public HotDog () : base ("hotdog", new string[] { "bread", "meat"}, new int[] { 1, 1 }, 0.7)
    {
    }
}
```

I tried to do this

```
Type t = typeof("HotDog");
if (t is Food) {
    Food f = (Food)Food.CreateOne (t);
}
```

This is my CreateOne method

```
public static Consumables CreateOne (Type t)
{
    return (Consumables)Activator.CreateInstance (t);
}
```

But I got the error that t is never of the provided Food type so the code inside is unreachable. Any idea what's wrong with this thing and how can I fix it?

Comment: `Hot Dog` != `HotDog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see it the problem is your if-statement.

```
Type t = typeof(...);
if (t is Food) { ... }
```

The `is` operator checks whether the type of the left expression is a valid value of the right expression.

In other words you are checking if the type of `t` (which is `Type`) is a valid value for the `Food` class, which of course it isn't.

What you can do is to use [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (typeof(Food).IsAssignableFrom(t)) { ... }
```

---

`IsAssignableFrom` determines whether an instance of the type `t` can be assigned to a variable of type `typeof(Food)`, i.e. if it returns true you can do

```
Hotdog h;
Food f;

if (typeof(Food).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Hotdog))
{
    f = h; // you can assign a Hotdog to a Food
}

// this would return false for your classes
if (typeof(Hotdog).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Food))
{
    h = f; // you can assign a Food to a Hotdog
}
```

Comment: That's correct @@. Still quite don't get the IsAssignableFrom. May you enlighten me a bit?

Comment: @TreeNguyen I've added an explanation, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
 Type t = typeof(HotDog)
```

See also [Type Checking: typeof, GetType, or is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is)

Comment: I have a Dictionary to return the Type for me so I don't think that's the problem :-?

Answer (score 1):

You need Reflection to get this to work.

First get the actual type HotDog:

```
Type t = Type.GetType("MyNamespace.HotDog");
```

Now create a new instance of this type:

```
HotDog instance = (HotDog) Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Note that this will call the default-constructor. If you need a parameterized one use `Activator#CreateInstance(t, object[])` instead.

Comment: Why use reflection out here when types can be directly accessed, created and invoked

Comment: Well, it also works without Type.GetType thats true, but anyway its Reflection when you use the Activator... However I concentrated on the OPs post itself where he´s using a string to get the actual type.

Comment: The problem is because HotDog is a kind of Food so I want to try if (t is Food). But it never returns true!