# Unable to check type of entity of base/inherited classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am having an issue with getting the types of a class based on using GetType() and typeof(), the issue being that it isn't working.

I have base class of Content and inherited classes of **Podcast** and AudioBook.

I am using Code First and have a Table per Hierarchy (which stores all child classes in one table with a Discriminator column) to store all the Content entities.

I want to query the Content table by the Title column, and return a Content entity. Then, based on the type (Podcast, AudioBook) do some other things. However the type check isn't working.

Models

```
public abstract class Content
{ 
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Podcast : Content
{

}
```

Repository

```
public Content FindContentByRoutingTitle(string routingTitle)
{
    var content = Context.ContentItems
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.RoutingTitle == routingTitle);

    return content;
}
```

Controller

```
var content = _contentRepository.FindContentByRoutingTitle(title);

if (content.GetType() == typeof(Podcast))
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Podcast", new { title = title });
}
else if (content.GetType() == typeof(Content))
{
    //just a check to see if equating with Content
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Podcast", new { title = title });
}
else
{
    //if/else block always falls to here.
    return RedirectToAction("NotFound", "Home");
}
```

Is there something I am missing here? Thanks for your help.

Reference: [Type Checking: typeof, GetType, or is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GetType()` returns the actual class of the object so if you try to compare it to `typeof(Content)` you will get `false`. However If you want to check if the variable derives from a base class I recommend 2 options.

- Option 1:

  ```
  if (content is Content)
  {
       //do code here
  }
  ```
- Option 2:

  ```
  if (content.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Content)))
  {
   //do code here
  }
  ```