# Polymorphism runtime object type check

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Consider the following classes:

```
class A
{
    public virtual string Name { get { return "A"; } }
}

class B : A
{
    public override string Name { get { return "B"; } }
}

class C : A
{
    public override string Name { get { return "C"; } }
}
```

And a list containing two objects of type B and one of type C:

```
List<A> l = new List<A>();
l.Add(new B());
l.Add(new C());
l.Add(new B());
```

Is there some way to force a check of the type at runtime and iterate only over the objects of type B in this list (short of writing a custom implementation of a list)? Something like:

```
foreach (B obj in l)               // runtime error
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);

// desired output:
//   B
//   B
```

I haven't run into this problem in a project, but the thought just occurred to me and I'm curious if this can be done. I'm aware the need for this feature could indicate a design flaw.

Comment: Check out [`Enumerable.OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type Checking: typeof, GetType, or is?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`.OfType<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
foreach (B obj in l.OfType<B>())
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
```

If you want *only* `B`s, and not any subclasses of `B` to be listed, you can use the following:

```
foreach (B obj in l.Where(o => o.GetType() == typeof(B)))
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
```

Comment: Awesome, `OfType<T>` was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the caveat about the subclasses as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach (A obj in l) 
{
    if (obj is B)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the simple approach I should have been thinking of myself. Thanks.