# How to find an object type in C#?

Tags: c#, object, types, casting

I've got a observable collection of objects of few known types, but when iterate on them I do not know the type of the current object.

How can I get the type of current object?

Comment: Probably, here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is

Comment: `object.GetType().Name` .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are only a few different types and you're taking a different action depending on the type then you can use `is` to check each type:

```
foreach(var thing in collection){
    if(thing is TypeA){
        doTypeA();
    }else if(thing is TypeB){
        doTypeB();
}
```

Another possible option, if it makes design sense and the objects are under your control, is to have them all implement an interface which includes a method to get an Enum describing the type? Then you can switch on that.

Answer (score 1):

To get a type of an object at runtime you should call [`GetType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.100).aspx) . If you know the objects can be of just a few known types you can use a [switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) statement:

```
Type t = obj.GetType();

switch (t.Name)
{
    case "Int32":
        Console.WriteLine("int type");
        break;
    case "String":
        Console.WriteLine("string type");
         break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Another type");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the GetType Method, as described here [GetType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Object.GetType()
```

If you have known types, you can check them with the typeof(object), as
described here: [typeof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/58918ffs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetType method. 
Like this:

```
ObservableCollection<object>  coll = new ObservableCollection<object>();

    var a = this.coll[0].GetType();
    var b = this.coll[1].GetType();
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have an ObservableCollection which has a generic type you can write something like this to get to know what's in it:

```
// Assume this is your observable collection
var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
Type type = observableCollection.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```