# Typeof not working as condition

Tags: c#, sqlite, object, types, typeof

I currently have a method to see what type of object an input is and create a SQL input based on it, Like so:

```
private static string PropertyToDBString(object o)
{
    Debug.Log(o.GetType());
    if (o == typeof(System.String) || o == typeof(string))
        return "'" + o.ToString() + "'";
    else if (o == typeof(System.Boolean) || o == typeof(bool))
        return ((System.Boolean)o) ? "1" : "0";

    return "'" + o.ToString() + "'";
}
```

But this does not seem to work, Everything returns as .toString() based, Boolean return as True/False, but the log is picking up the type as system.boolean. Like so:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUZe5.png)

I'm using SQLite and wondering if I should bother using proper data types, As limits don't exist and even the fact the boolean column is INT(1) on the DB but still stores True/False. Should I just use TEXT for everything.

Comment: I haven't done C# for a while, but `o == typeof` doesn't look right. Something like `o.type == typeof` makes more sense. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is

Comment: If your question has been answered to your satisfaction, please choose an answer to close this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I currently have a method to see what type of object an input is and create a SQL input based on it

**Don't do that.** Use parameterized SQL instead. You should *not* be trying to format your values for use in SQL. This is almost *always* going to be a route to SQL injection attacks.

Now, as to the problem itself... you're checking whether `o` itself is `typeof(bool)` - whereas I suspect you want to check whether `o.GetType()` is `typeof(bool)`.

Better yet, use the `is` operator:

```
if (o is string)
{
    return "'" + o + "'";
}
if (o is bool)
{
    bool value = (bool) o;
    return value ? "1" : "0";
}
// Are you sure you want this? I would throw an exception if you
// don't know what to do with the value...
return "'" + o + "'";
```

Comment: @TristanCunningham: It's very, very unclear what you're trying to do - but as I say, you shouldn't be trying to format SQL parameters. I suggest you consider creating a new question which gives more detail about how you're trying to use this, so we can help you use SQL parameters properly.

Answer (score 2):

If you use parameters in your SQL, you don't need to worry about datatypes or single quotes.

For an insert, instead of:

```
com.CommandText = "Insert into MyTable (ID,Name,Birthday,Age) values (12,'Bob','01/01/1980',24)";
```

you do:

```
com.CommandText = "Insert into MyTable (ID,Name,Birthday,Age) values (@ID,@Name,@BD,@Age)";
    int ID = 12;
    string Name = "Bob";
    DateTime Birthday = new DateTime(1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    Int Age = 24;
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
    com.Parameters.AddWthValue("@BD", Birthday);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", Age);
```

for a Boolean input, you can do:

```
bool isTrue = true;
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isHappyCustomer",isTrue ? 1 : 0);
```

When using parameters, you don't NEED to use the same datatype as in the database - as long as the value itself will match the requirements of the database field. So you could send a string to a date like

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date","1/1/2016");
```

for a date field, or

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age","24");
```

for an int field. Though it's always a good idea to use the same data types and not rely on this conversion feature IMO.