# how to get actual data type for Var in C#

Tags: c#

For below code, the "GetType()" is same (String) for Var result & result1.

```
var result = "abc";
        var result1 = "10.17";

        string a = result.GetType().Name;
        string b = result1.GetType().Name;
```

How to get actual data type for above variables?

Comment: Because result1 is also a string having number in it. It type is not numeric.

Comment: Actual data type for both is indeed `string`, and you got it. @ThePerplexedOne `typeof(result)` won't even compile.

Comment: If youre in the debugger. Hover oflver the var keyword and it will tell you what the type is.

Comment: I brainfarted with my previous comment. Check this for information regarding type checking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "actual data type" you, probably, mean "can the data be treated (converted) as double, int" etc. If it's your case, try using `TryParse`, possible **C# 7.0** (`out var` construction) implementation:

```
    var result1 = "10.17";

    if (int.TryParse(result, out var intValue)) {
      // result1 can be treated as int - intValue
    }
    else if (double.TryParse(result, 
                             NumberStyles.Any, 
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                             out var doubleValue)) {
      // result1 can be treated as double - doubleValue
    }
    else {
      // result1 is a string which can't be converted to int, double 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables declare using **var** are implicitly typed variables but are (different to using *dynamic*) strongly typed. So the variable you use will have the type of the value you assign to it and it is not possible to assign values of another type.

```
string a = "foobar";
var b = "foobar";
int c = 10;
var d = 10;
```

**a** and **b** will both be of type string. Because b gets a string assigned. So are **c** and **d** both of type int.

This will generate a compiler error

```
var a = "foobar";
var i = 10;
a = i;
```

Because you can't assign an int to a variable of type string.

For more information on **var** take a look at the [var (C# reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
string a ="12.22";
int result;

double result1;
string ans = string.Empty;

if(int.TryParse(a,out result))
{
  ans = "Integer";
}
else if(double.TryParse(a,out  result1))
{
  ans = "double";
}
else
{
  ans = "string";
}
```

Comment: read this and format your code :
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.