# c# using lambda to check if an object is of a certain dynamic type (passed via a parameter)

Tags: c#, lambda, types

I have a method that checks if a certain document is of a certain type and chooses to do something about it :

```
 private void OpenOrActivateDocument(Type FormType)
 {    var doc = dmMain.View.Documents.
          Where(x => x.Form is FormType).
          Select(x=>x).First();

          // do something about the found (or not found) doc
 }
```

this is a sample method that calls the above method:

```
private void button1_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        OpenOrActivateDocument(typeof(BudgetExtractionWindow));
}
```

however, I get an error here : "Where(x => x.Form is FormType)". If I were to change this to a specific type (that is not passed via the parameters), then i would not have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it this way:

```
 private void OpenOrActivateDocument(Type FormType)
 {    var doc = dmMain.View.Documents.
          Where(x => x.Form.GetType() == FormType)
          .FirstOrDefault();

      if (doc != null){
          // do something about the found doc
      } else {
          //not found, do some other things
      }    
 }
```

The `FormType` is actually an `object` instance named `FormType` with class type `Type`. It does *not* represent any class name like what you normally use in class instance declaration: `ClassType instance = new ClassType()`.

If you want to check if your `x.Form` is of that type, you should use object's method `GetType`.

Also, you could remove the `Select` clause as it will be redundant.

`FirstOrDefault` is to make it return `null` when not found instead of throwing exception.

Comment: Great thanks a lot! 

Just a simple follow up, what's the difference between .GetType() == <Type> and using the "is"?

Comment: [GetType() vs is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is)

Comment: @JeremyLoh you are welcome... :) and welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: The `is` is more similar to `FormType.IsAssignableFrom(x.Form.GetType())` than to `==`.