# Check if instance is a collection of given type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Let's say I have this dummy code:

```
var object1 = new Test();
```

So, if I need check if `object1` is an instance of `Test` class I can do:

```
var type = typeof(Test);
Console.WriteLine(object1.GetType() == type); // will print true
```

But now I have this `object2` (A list of `Test` objects):

```
var object2 = new List<Test>
{
    new Test(),
    new Test(),
    new Test()
};
```

**My question is:** How can I check if `object2` is a list of `Test` instances?

Comment: `if (object2.GetType() == typeof(List<Test>))` ? That's easy. But you should really use the `is` operator instead of calling `GetType()`: `if (object1 is Test)` or `if (object2 is List<Test>)`.

Comment: Do you want to check that all items in the collection are specifically of type `Test`, as opposed to one of its subclasses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about?

```
  Type myListElementType = object2.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single();
  if (myListElementType  == typeof(Test))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could either use `.GetType()` to afterwards compare it to the `typeof(List<Test>)` ..

```
if (object2.GetType() == typeof(List<Test>))
{
    // do something
}
```

.. or you could use the `is` expression like:

```
if (object2 is List<Test>)
{
    // do something
}
```

These `if`-statements will be true if `object2` is a `List` of `Test`-objects.

**Note**
Both fit for what you want to do but there are also some differences between `.GetType()`, `typeof(..)` and `is`. These are explained here: [Type Checking: typeof, GetType, or is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is)

Comment: @RufusL `is` is recommended. It makes for more readable code, it handles the case where `object2` is `null`, and in C#7 you can write `if (object2 is List<Test> foo) { Console.WriteLine(foo.Count); }`.

Comment: @RufusL oRole just reminded me, `is` is true if it's a subclass, equivalent to `Type.IsAssignableFrom()` -- so if you want to check *exact* type equality, excluding subclasses, comparing `GetType() == ` is the only choice in that case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more generic method of finding the type bound to the list by reflecting over the interfaces implemented on the underlying `IList`. This is an extension method I use for finding the bound type:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the underlying type bound to an IList. For example, if the list
/// is List{string}, the result will be typeof(string).
/// </summary>
public static Type GetBoundType( this IList list )
{
    Type type = list.GetType();

    Type boundType = type.GetInterfaces()
        .Where( x => x.IsGenericType )
        .Where( x => x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>) )
        .Select( x => x.GetGenericArguments().First() )
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return boundType;
}
```

In the O.P.'s case:

```
bool isBound = object2.GetBoundType() == typeof(Test);
```