# How to skip off date in TimeScaleData (read mpp file)?

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-project

I want to display the work hours of all days from 29/5 to 30/6 but in the interval. It contains Saturdays and Sundays (non-working days). I use `TimeScaleData` but it auto-stops when it sees a non-working day. I try to add(1) to the finish day but it still stops, so I can't display the work hours correctly.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application();
app.FileOpenEx(Path, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    PjPoolOpen.pjPoolReadWrite, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Project pj = app.ActiveProject;
foreach(Resource re in pj.Resources)
{
    foreach (Assignment assign in re.Assignments)
    {
        double h = 0;
        var tsvs = assign.TimeScaleData("5/29/2017", "7/1/2017", MSProject.PjAssignmentTimescaledData.pjAssignmentTimescaledWork, MSProject.PjTimescaleUnit.pjTimescaleDays, 1);
        try
        {
            foreach (TimeScaleValue tsv in tsvs)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < totalday ; i++)
                {
                    h += Convert.ToDouble(tsv.Value); //sum all value
                }     
            }

        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code encounters a run-time error on this line: `h += tsv.Value` because `tsv.Value` is an empty string for days there is no work. Check the datatype of  `tsv.Value` before trying to add.

[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/timescalevalue-value-property-project)—note that the Value property returns a Variant, not a double.

Comment: it works. Bugs and bugs, i feel stress :v :v Thanks so much Rachel.

Comment: Hi @Rachel, I research and detect funtion Val in VBA. That post said:""tsv.Value returns an empty string ("") for time slices outside the object's date range. Val(tsv.Value) converts the empty string to a zero which is much more useful"".I understood  Val() like Convert.ToDouble in C# but when i use it sees error same above.

Comment: Check the datatype of `tsv.Value` before using it. See [this SO post for type checking in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is).

Comment: Finally, i looking for my issue. I added GC.Collect(). Thanks so much Rachel.

Comment: I try to access timescaledata but it's slowly(results 600 rows but it runs > 3'). I used Application.Sort(Resource Name, Start, Unique ID) but still doesn't work. Can you explain help me??Thanks Rachel

Comment: 1) Remove your inner loop `for (int i = 0; i < totalday ; i++)`. At best it is unnecessary, at worst you are adding the same `tsv.Value` multiple times. 2) Check the data type of` tsv.Value` before trying to add it (rather than forcing all values to be converted). 3) Sort is irrelevant here.

Comment: FYI: The com exception that `GC.Collect` solved was fixed in Project 2010.

Comment: Really, I use Project 2007 and it has a problem with GC.Collect. Yap, I think sort data will  group clusters with same start day , I'm so bad :( :( .

Comment: I removed loop for. @Rachel, I don't understand clearly about check the data type of tsv.Value, I follwed your link but i'm feel vague.

Answer (score 0):

In my code tsv.value returned an empty string when iterating through the timescalevalues. Checking for IsNumeric worked:

```
Private Sub ProcessAssignments(T As Task)

    Dim A As Assignment
    Dim tsvsHours As TimeScaleValues
    Dim tsvsCosts0 As TimeScaleValues
    Dim dblWork As Double
    Dim curCostClassA As Double


    ' Process assignments
    For Each A In T.Assignments
        ' Get the timescale collection objects for Hours and Costs
        tsvsHours = A.TimeScaleData(
            StartDate:=T.BaselineStart,
            EndDate:=T.BaselineFinish,
            Type:=PjAssignmentTimescaledData.pjAssignmentTimescaledBaselineWork,
            TimeScaleUnit:=PjTimescaleUnit.pjTimescaleMonths,
            Count:=1)

        tsvsCosts0 = A.TimeScaleData(
            StartDate:=T.BaselneStart,
            EndDate:=T.BaselineFinish,
            Type:=PjAssignmentTimescaledData.pjAssignmentTimescaledBaselineCost,
            TimeScaleUnit:=PjTimescaleUnit.pjTimescaleMonths,
            Count:=1)

        ' Iterate through the assignment timescalevalues
        For i As Integer = 1 To tsvsCosts0.Count
            If IsNumeric(tsvsCosts0(i).Value) = True Then 'Cannot process non-working times with an empty string value

                ' Get the hours from the tsvsHours collection
                If IsNumeric(tsvsHours(i).Value) Then
                    dblWork = CDbl(tsvsHours(i).Value / 60)
                Else
                    dblWork = 0
                End If

                ' Get the costs from the Baseline collection
                If IsNumeric(tsvsCosts0(i).Value) Then
                    curCostClassA = tsvsCosts0(i).Value
                Else
                    curCostClassA = 0
                End If


                ' Do stuff here

            End If
        Next i

        tsvsHours = Nothing
        tsvsCosts0 = Nothing

    Next A
End Sub
```

Comment: I checked but i don't know it works incoorect. Example, 2 rows have duplicate start,finish day and day works. But row1 is right reult but no2 incorrect.

Comment: I updated the example to provide a fully working sub. Maybe something was off in the timescalevalues collection?

Comment: Yah, Thanks Eric@@ Due to code reading more than 9 time slices. I added GC.Collect() and it's fine.

Comment: FYI: If you are using the TimeScaleData method to get baseline units (e.g. BaselineWork), you should use the corresponding baseline dates as the start and finish points (not forecast start and finish).

Comment: @RachelHettinger That is usually true; example revised to reflect baseline start and finish.