# Is there any way to check the type regardless its inheritance tree? but inside of function

Tags: c#, wpf, types, gettype

I wanted to check the class type regardless inheritance tree, amongst the children of Canvas. so I made a reusable function like below.

```
private int FindIndexOf(Type _t)
    {
        if (wrappingGrid == null)
            return -1;

        for(int i =0; i< wrappingGrid.Children.Count; ++i)
        {
            if(wrappingGrid.Children[i].GetType() == _t)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

But it works with only type-strict.

```
wrappingGrid.Children[i] is _t
```

This doesn't work either because the 'Type' type is not what I want to compare with. and it causes a syntax error.
Probably I need to make a template function.
But I'd better write simpler code.

I've already looked into other articles as well.
[Type Checking: typeof, GetType, or is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is)

Do you have any idea?
Thank you in advance..

Comment: Try `_t.IsAssignableFrom(wrappingGrid.Children[i].GetType())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you should try `wrappingGrid.Children[i].GetType().IsSubClassOf(_t)`

EDIT
@usr:
Yes: IsAssignableFrom is better, but then it has to be called vice versa:

`_t.IsAssignableFrom(wrappingGrid.Children[i].GetType()`

Comment: I think IsSubClassOf says false for equal types. You have to use IsAssignableFrom.