# Try cast to a child type and if it doesn't work cast to a different child type c#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm trying to make a function that can take in a parameter of class Parent that is actually of either type Child1, Child2, or Child3. I want to do something different based on which child type it is and I can't think of a way to do it other than what I am showing below. This feels wrong to me so any suggestions for a better way to do this would be much appreciated.

```
public static bool DoStuff(Parent parent)
{
    try
    {
        Child1 child = parent as Child1;
        DoStuffChild1(child);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        try
        {
            Child2 child = parent as Child2;
            DoStuffChild2(child);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            try
            {
                Child3 child = parent as Child3;
                DoStuffChild3(child);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                HandleError();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is C# 7 an option? The pattern matching feature is certainly a better solution than this.

Comment: Even excluding that, why do you need the exception handling? If the cast fails then child should be `null`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, this is wrong. Not only would I reject this in a code review I'd take you out back and shoot you ;) Look up `typeof` and `.GetType()` - if you want, I'll write an answer covering those options.

Comment: Yeah, like @EvanTrimboli said, this won't work the way you're expecting it to as-is, since the cast failure will just result in an assignment of null rather than an exception.

Comment: I assume it's catching the NullReferenceException that ends up occurring. So, exceptions as control flow.

Comment: @JonathonChase Nothing in the code shown would throw a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: @RufusL - It certainly could depending on how `DoStuffChild1` etc are implemented.

Comment: @Lee that doesn't make it right ;)

Comment: @Lee I meant the explicit code shown. Yes, it could throw that or just as likely an `ArgumentNullException` depending on how those methods were implemented.

Comment: I know this would work because Visual Studio required a try-catch around the "as" cast here for the case where it cannot cast it to the child class. However, it is so disgusting that I could never submit for any sort of review. @EvilGeniusJamie I almost wanted to take myself out back and soot me for thinking of this. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using C# 7.0 or later, you can achieve what you're looking for with the below code:

```
if (parent is Child1 child1)
{
    DoStuffChild1(child1);
}
else if (parent is Child2 child2)
{
    DoStuffChild2(child2);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome. Just what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `is` keyword instead:

```
public static bool DoStuff(Parent parent)
{
            try
            {
                if (parent is Child1)
                {
                    Child1 child = parent;
                    DoStuffChild1(child);
                }
                else if (parent is Child2)
                {
                    Child2 child = parent;
                    DoStuffChild2(child);
                }
                else if (parent is Child3)
                {
                    Child3 child = parent;
                    DoStuffChild3(child);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                HandleError();
            }
}
```

> **is** returns true if an instance is in the inheritance tree.

Additionally, following is a very good answer on type checking:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/983061/4222487

Comment: You can even add a variable name after to automatically create the variable. `if (parent is Child1 child1) { DoStuffChild1(child1); }`

Comment: @BlakeThingstad I believe that's true as of C#7 ?

Comment: Or if you're not on C#7, you can just do: `if (parent is Child1) { DoStuffChild1((Child1) parent); }`

Comment: @EvilGeniusJamie Yes, it is part of Pattern Matching as far as I understand. It is discussed some in the [Pattern Matching documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching)

Comment: Thanks. My only error I was handling was it not being any of the possible types. I should have clarified a little better. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @cpcolella glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This method will work on older versions of C# if C# 7 is not an option.

---

Don't use `try`/`catch` as control flow. Ever.

If you need to do something different depending on the class of the object, you can use `typeof` and `.GetType()`. In your example

```
public static bool DoStuff(Parent parent)
{
    if (parent.GetType() == typeof(Child1))
    {
        Child1 child = parent as Child1;
        DoStuffChild1(child);
    }
    else if (parent.GetType() == typeof(Child2))
    {
        Child2 child = parent as Child2;
        DoStuffChild2(child);
    }
    else if (parent.GetType() == typeof(Child3))
    {
        Child3 child = parent as Child3;
        DoStuffChild3(child);
    }
    else
    {
        HandleError();
    }
}
```

is a simple way to handle it.

---

The reason you would use this over the `is` keyword in FaizanRabbani's answer is that this method is a strict type check, ignoring super-classes - for example:

```
if (parent is Parent)
```

would evaluate `true`, but

```
if (parent.GetType() == typeof(Parent))
```

would evaluate `false`, if it was `Child1`, `Child2` or `Child3`, for example.

Comment: Note: @rufus-l 's comment on the question is the reason I took try/catch out completely

Comment: Thank you. I do have C# 7 available to me.

Comment: Would the down-voter care to explain what's wrong with this answer...?