# Object.GetType() is never System.DateTime?

Tags: c#

Code line below prints `System.Datetime`

```
log.InfoFormat("{0}", row[2].GetType());
```

But `row[2].GetType()` is never equals to `System.DateTime` in condition below.

```
f.TestDate = (row[2].GetType() is System.DateTime) ? f.TestDate = (System.DateTime)row[2] : f.TestDate = DateTime.MinValue;
```

Why?

Comment: GetType() is Type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type Checking: typeof, GetType, or is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is)

Comment: What type is `row`?

Answer (score 5):

```
row[2].GetType() is System.DateTime
```

does not check whether `row[2]` is of the type `System.DateTime` but whether the `Type` instance returned by `GetType()` is (which it obviously isn't)

Just use

```
row[2] is System.DateTime
```

Comment: Actually, his line can be shortened to `f.TestDate = (row[2] as DateTime?) ?? DateTime.MinValue`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
row[2].GetType() == typeof(DateTime)
```

or

```
row[2] is DateTime
```