# Which data type should I use for list of string values in the parameter declaration of my CallBimlScript?

Tags: c#, biml

I want to pass the value of a string array as a parameter into a CallBimlScript, like the value assigned here:

```
// Retrieve table list into string array 
var tablesToInclude = ExternalDataAccess.GetDataTable(connectionWrk.ConnectionString,  
                                      "SELECT DISTINCT [TABLE_NAME] " +
                                      "FROM [ETL_WORK].[STG_TBL_CONFIG] " +
                                      "WHERE [TABLE_SCHEMA] = 'STG' " +
                                      "AND [LOAD_CONFIG] IN ('PAT','TAP'); "
                                      ).Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(r => r[0].ToString());
```

Which I'm passing into a CallBimlScript with this call:

```
<#=CallBimlScript("DoStuffWithTableNames.biml", connectionWrk, tablesToInclude)>
```

And here's the header of the BimlScript I'm calling:

```
<#@ property name="connectionWrk" type="Varigence.Languages.Biml.Connection.AstOleDbConnectionNode" #>
<#@ property name="tablesToInclude" type="?" #>
```

Which data type is compatible with the variable I'm using in the CallBimlScript?

Answer (score 0):

The GetDataTable method returns [System.Data.DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.7.2) But you using Linq to extract the first element of the data row as a string

I'd have to check, but I think you need to chain a ToArray or ToList to the expression and then you'd need to specify to correct enumerable iterable type in the target Biml script.

Otherwise, you should be able to ask the type by using the [System.Type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983061/181965) class to determine what type is generated in the Linq call.

Comment: Well, @billinkc, here's what I get for the type: System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Data.DataRow,System.String[]]. I have not found a way to specify this type in the callee, yet.