# How to override renderers for different Entries throughout the application?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, types

I'm setting up different designs for two different custom `Entry` `LoginEntry` and a `CommonEntry` for my application and I want to be able to override the renderer for these two different scenarios for different designs throughout the application.

I have the following code that I tried but it's getting an error for `LoginEntry` is a type which is not valid for this context.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
{    
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (e.OldElement != null) return;

    if (e.NewElement == LoginEntry)
    {
        UpdateEntryStyle();
    }
}
```

[image: Bug Error]

Comment: `if (e.NewElement is LoginEntry)`

Comment: Hi , have you solved this ?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Yes, I solved it using Jason's comment.

Comment: @Mochi Great , you can update in answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `==` operator, in C#, is used to mostly compare values (for primitive types like `int` and `char`) or references (for objects). It cannot be used to compare an object to a Type, as you're trying to do in your example.

When trying to compare types you should do a Type Check, which methods are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983061/9629238).