# C# - Type check an interface

Tags: c#

I am building a StateMachine. For my States I use an interface:

```
public interface IState
{
    void Enter();
    void Execute();
    void Exit();
}
```

I always have a `IState currentState` active, I would like to check which type of State it is. Lets say I have `WalkingState` and `RunningState`, I would like to check which one is currently Active.

I tried something like:

```
public bool IsCurrentState<T>()
{
    return (Type)currentState == typeof(T);
}
```

But It does not allow me to cast currentState to a Type, and nothing else I've tried has worker either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like this

```
public bool IsCurrentState<T>() {
    return currentState is T ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```cs
currentState.GetType() == typeof(T)
```

**Edit:**

As mentioned in [Rajan Prasad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60799933/c-sharp-type-check-an-interface/60800002#60800002), you can use `is`. `is` and `GetType() == typeof(T)` behave differently. Primarily:

- If `A : B`, `instanceOfA is instanceOfB` is `true` while `instanceOfA.GetType() == typeof(B)` is `false`.

If you have only 1 level of inheritance from `IState` (i.e only `FirstLevelState : IState`, no `SecondLevelState : FirstLevelState`) use `is`, it is more performant and has fewer edge cases. Otherwise, use `GetType() == typeof(T)`.

This question details type checking method differences: [Type Checking: typeof, GetType, or is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is).

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use Type.IsAssignableFrom (). He requires two instaces of System.Type, because you havent to have statically declared type. It differents on the other parts your code, but you should know about it.