# Why is typeof(T) != instance.getType()?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm working on a factory which shall return a generic implementation of an interface according to a type.

My main question is being illustrated by
[image]
Why are these typeof(TException) != exception.GetType()? Respectively, what do I have to change to have the correct type for TException?

The above code results in a InvalidCast exception because it tries to cast to  `IDocumedisExceptionHandler<DocumedisException>` instead of `IDocumedisExceptionHandler<FhirParsingException>`

Factory implementation:

```
internal class DocumedisExceptionHandlerFactory : IDocumedisExceptionHandlerFactory
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, object> _exceptionHandlers = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object>();

    public void RegisterExceptionHandler<TException>(IDocumedisExceptionHandler<TException> exceptionHandler)
        where TException : DocumedisException
    {
        _exceptionHandlers.Add(typeof(TException), exceptionHandler);
    }

    public IDocumedisExceptionHandler<TException> GetDocumedisExceptionHandler<TException>(TException exception)
        where TException : DocumedisException
    {
        _exceptionHandlers.TryGetValue(exception.GetType(), out var exceptionHandler);
        return (IDocumedisExceptionHandler<TException>) exceptionHandler;
    }
}
```

Side question: Would there be a better way then using `object` as dictionary value?

Registration of the handler in startup:

```
var exceptionHandlerFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IDocumedisExceptionHandlerFactory>();
exceptionHandlerFactory.RegisterExceptionHandler(new FhirParsingExceptionHandler());
```

Where `FhirParsingExceptionHandler` implements `IDocumedisExceptionHandler`

```
internal class FhirParsingExceptionHandler : IDocumedisExceptionHandler<FhirParsingException>
{
    public void HandleException(FhirParsingException exception, out HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, out OperationOutcome.IssueType issueType, out string message)
    {
        httpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        issueType = OperationOutcome.IssueType.Invalid;
        message = exception.Message;
    }
}
```

Handler definition (where `TException` is contravariant):

```
public interface IDocumedisExceptionHandler<in TException>
    where TException : DocumedisException
{
    void HandleException(TException exception, out HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, out OperationOutcome.IssueType issueType, out string message);
}
```

And `FhirParsingException` extends `DocumedisException`:

```
public class FhirParsingException : DocumedisException
{
   [...]
}
```

Retrieval of the handler from the middleware:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
   try
   {
      await _next.Invoke(context);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      if (ex is DocumedisException documedisException)
      {
         await HandleDocumedisExceptionAsync(context, documedisException);
      }
      else
      {
         throw;
      }
   }
}

private async Task HandleDocumedisExceptionAsync<TException>(HttpContext context, TException ex, MedicationAnalyzerErrorCode? errorCode = null)
   where TException : DocumedisException
{
   var exceptionHandler = _documedisExceptionHandlerFactory.GetDocumedisExceptionHandler(ex);
   [...]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type Checking: typeof, GetType, or is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Not really. It explains the differences, but not how I can get TException of the correct type. As explained by InBetween, it is determined at compile time.

Comment: How is `IDocumedisExceptionHandler<TException>` declared? Is covariant against `TException` or not? It seems, that your question is related to generics mostly

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski It is contravariant (only because resharper told me to do so). I've edited the question to include the interface

Comment: Then you cast is not valid, it'll work in case of covariant generic interface. You should spend some time to refine your current approach and code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`typeof(TException)` gives you the *compile time* type of `exception`. `exception.GetType()` gives you the *runtime* type of `exception`. These two need not be the same at all, the only guarantee the compiler makes is that the runtime type of `exception` will be assignable to a `TException` variable.

Consider the following:

```
class Animal { }
class Turtle: Animal { }
bool CheckTypes<T>(T animal) where T: Animal 
{
     return typeof(T) == animal.GetType();
}
```

And now you have:

```
Animal animal = new Turtle();
Feed(animal);
```

Rest assured, `CheckTypes` will return `false`; the type of the generic type argument is `Animal` but the runtime type of `animal` is really `Turtle`.

Comment: This answers the main question of the why, thanks for that! But I don't see a way to solve my issue to retrieve a typed handler, expecting an exact exception type, from the factory. I could pass DocumedisException and cast it in the handler but would really like to avoid that,

Comment: @Philipple Show the `IDocumedisExceptionHandler<T>` interface. If you can make it covariant (`IDocumedisExceptionHandler<out T>`) then the cast should succeed; same as `IEnumerable<Turtle>` can be cast to `IEnumerable<Animal>`. If its contravariant or invariant then you are stuck in this current set up.

Comment: I've added the interface definition as Pavel also requested. I'll have to do some readining about co- and contra-variant..

Comment: @Philippe The interface is contravariant, therefore the cast you are attempting is not valid.

Comment: I couldn't figure out a way to make it covariant in the time I had at my disposal. I made it non-generic by passing DocumedisException to the handler. The handler can then cast it if required. Not perfect, but fully functional.

Comment: @philippe good decision. Sometimes when the type system is fighting against you, the best solution is to take a step back and approach the problem from a different angle. Generics is very useful but its not always the best tool for every job.