# Why GetProperties() does not return properties when using typeof() but it does when using GetType()?

Tags: c#

I have a C# code that would look at every public-property on a class and creates a collection of the key and value. The key is simply a dot-notation variable to access the property;

I have the following models

```cs
public class Home
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address 
{
    public Street Street { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
}

public class Street
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have the following function

```cs
public void GetPropertyKeyValue<T>(T obj, string prefix, List<ExtractedTerm> pairs)
{
    if (pairs == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pairs));
    }

    // This works of the first object, but fails on the class properties
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        string key = property.Name;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(prefix))
        {
            key = $"{prefix}.{property.Name}";
        }

        Type type = property.PropertyType;
        object value = property.GetValue(obj, null);

        if (type.IsClass && !type.IsInterface && !type.IsEnum && !type.IsPrimitive && !type.IsString())
        {
            GetPropertyKeyValue(value, key, ref pairs);

            continue;
        }

        pairs.Add(new ExtractedTerm(key, value, property.PropertyType));
    }
}
```

The above method is called like this

```cs
var home = new Home() {
   Id = "100",
   Summary = "Test",
   Address = new Address() {
       CityName = "Los Angeles"
   }
}

var pairs = new List<ExtractedTerm>();
GetPropertyKeyValue(home, null, pairs);
```

The above code works perfectly on the `Home.Id` and `Home.Summary` and `Home.Address` But sine the `Address` is property of a class type, so the `GetPropertyKeyValue` method is recursively being called. When `Address` is passed the code `typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)` does not return any properties. However, the code `obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)` returns the properties expected. But I can't really count of `obj.GetType()` as obj could be null. As you noticed in the example above the `Street` property is null and `obj.GetType()` will throw an exception.

Why `typeof()` works in some cases but not always? How can I get the properties always even when `obj` is null?

Comment: In recursive calls to `GetPropertyKeyValue`, `T` is bound to `object`. The difference between `GetType` and `typeof` is that `typeof(T)` provides reflection metadata for compile-time type of T, which is that of `object`, whilst `GetType` provides reflection metadata of the run-time type, which in your case would be `Address` and `Street`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type Checking: typeof, GetType, or is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is)

Comment: typeof only gives static values known at compile time. TypeOf gives you runtime instance type. They are different. You can rely on obj.GetType(), because if obj is NULL it has no properties for you to access in the first place. . You can easily prevent it from blowing up when you try to access it when it is null with the null-conditional operator

Comment: Your `GetPropertyKeyValue` shouldn't be generic and use `T`, which is a static compile time type for the parameter `obj`. Instead, you should be using `GetType`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Type inference happens at compile time.**

In other words, since `value` is of static type `object`,

```
object value = property.GetValue(obj, null);
```

the following line:

```
GetPropertyKeyValue(value, key, ref pairs);
```

gets compiled as

```
GetPropertyKeyValue<object>(value, key, ref pairs);
```

and `typeof(object)` yields ... well ... the `object` type.

---

How to solve this? Instead of making the method generic, pass in a parameter of type `Type`. That way, you can just pass `property.PropertyType` in the recursive invocation. I would suggest the following signature:

```
public void GetPropertyKeyValue<T>(T obj, string prefix, List<ExtractedTerm> pairs)
{
    return GetPropertyKeyValue(typeof(T), obj, prefix, pairs);
}

private void GetPropertyKeyValue(Type type, object obj, string prefix, List<ExtractedTerm> pairs)
{
    // contains your logic and recursively calls the non-generic version
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> GetPropertyKeyValue(string ClassName)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> Values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
       System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] Properties = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().First(x => x.Name == ClassName).GetProperties();

        foreach (System.Reflection .PropertyInfo property in Properties)
        {
            Values.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().First(x => x.Name == ClassName)));
        }
        return Values;
    }
```