# Mark method Obsolete except for calls within the same class

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want to mark a method as Obsolete only for callers from out of its class, while letting methods in its class call it without a warning.

Is that possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is

Comment: No. The `ObsoleteAttribute` cannot be applied conditionally. It's either obsolete or it's not. Compile-time warning directives also  can't be applied conditionally. Just add a helpful description in the workaround text indicating it will be changed from `public` to `private` in the future (or whatever you're planning on doing with it).

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to do this. Can you give an example where this is needed? Is suppressing the warning on a particular line an option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could extract the method content to a new private method.
Internally you would use the private one.

```cs
public class YourClass
{
    [Obsolete]
    public void YourMethod()
    {
        YourMethodLogicExtractedToPrivateMethod();
    }

    private void YourMethodLogicExtractedToPrivateMethod()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good workaround. Thanks. I'm accepting for now, unless someone comes around with a way to achieve a private Obsolete after all.

Comment: @ispiro There's none. Your best option is to either use a private method for obsolete methods and private backing fields for obsolete properties, or to suppress the warning.